# Android SQLite rawquery with Date String in WHERE clause not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to get all data if today date is in
between two dates that i have already stored in the table as strings in (in yyyy-MM-dd format).
I tried several ways but nothing worked out.

If i try this in following way it is working fine and receiving correct values.(count = 4)

```
public int getMedicineDataFromDate() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String dates = "'2018-11-26'";
    String stext = "SELECT * FROM " + MED_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + dates + " BETWEEN STARTING_DATE AND ENDING_DATE";

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(stext, null);

    return  cursor.getCount();

}
```

But what i want to do this by passing date from my activity 
as in following way.And this way i get empty cursor (count = 0).

**Inside my activity**

```
 Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 SimpleDateFormat e = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 String todayString = e.format(today);

 int result = mydb.getMedicineDataFromDate(todayString);
 String resl = Integer.toString(result);

 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data received " + resl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**In DatabaseHelper class**

```
 public int getMedicineDataFromDate(String date) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String stext = "SELECT * FROM " + MED_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + date + " BETWEEN STARTING_DATE AND ENDING_DATE";

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(stext, null);

    return  cursor.getCount();

}
```

If someone can explain me why i am getting 0 as the count in second way and what is the correct
way to do this.it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Because you are missing single quotes around the date string in the second case.  Instead, use: `String todayString = "'" + e.format(today) + "'";`

Comment: But, you should learn about using statements in Java, which can help to avoid these types of errors.

Comment: also you are not passing values of start date and end date. You are passing them as string

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you very much, appreciate your help.I am still studying i will pay attention to your suggestion.

Comment: @VivekMishra Start dates and End dates have already saved in my db.So i thought this method is enough.Any way it gives me correct values.Is this a bad way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have not enclosed the String in single quotes and therefore it is interpreted as if it is numeric and thus a calculation.

That is the resultant SQL (assuming the date is 2018-11-26 which mathematically is 2018 minus 11 minus 26 = 1981) would be :-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 1981 BETWEEN STARTING_DATE AND ENDING_DATE
```

You could change `String todayString = e.format(today);` to be `String todayString = "'" + e.format(today) + "'";`

Or you could use :-

```
String stext = "SELECT * FROM " + MED_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ? BETWEEN STARTING_DATE AND ENDING_DATE";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(stext, new String[]{date}); //<<<<<<<<<< will place quotes around the string for you
```

Or you could use :-

```
public int getMedicineDataFromDate(String date) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "? BETWEEN STARTING_DATE AND ENDING_DATE";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{date};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MED_TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    int rv = cursor.getCount();
    cusror.close();
    return  rv;   
}
```

- **Note in all cases you should close the Cursor, as is shown in the last option, before returning, otherwise the Cursor's remain open and you have the potential of an exception due to too many being open.**
- The above is in-principle code and has not been checked or run and therefore may have some errors.

Comment: This is the correct answer.Thank you very much.Your explanation is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is there.

```
 SimpleDateFormat e = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 String todayString = e.format(today);
```

You change todayString value as String like

```
  String todayString ="'"+e.format(today)+"'";
```

this.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working . This is the easiest and simplest solution.